# Ternary expressions, skipping to a second condition when the first one is true

Tags: ternary

I'm new to coding and I don't know all the vocabulary yet. Here's an exercice I'm stuck on. 
Use a series of ternary operator to set the category to one of the following:
 *   - "herbivore" if an animal eats plants
 *   - "carnivore" if an animal eats animals
 *   - "omnivore" if an animal eats plants and animals
 *   - undefined if an animal doesn't eat plants or animals

My code starts like this.

```
var eatsPlants = true;
var eatsAnimals = false;

var category = eatsPlants ? "herbivore" : "carnivore" /* this is where I'm stuck (lol), when my first condition is true the code runs automatically. How do I get to my "omnivore" (true, true) "undefined" (false, false) condition? */

console.log(category);
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var category = (eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "omnivore" : (eatsPlants && !eatsAnimals) ? "herbivore" : (!eatsPlants && eatsAnimals) ? "carnivore" : undefined
```

Comment: I was stuck on trying to make it with work with 2 conditions.... I didn't think of separating the problem into more of them. Thanks Asrul!